# Adding DataGridComboBoxColumn in WPF from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I would like to add DataGridComboBoxColumn in WPF from C# code. I would like to bind the combobox with an existing enum also.

Here is my DataGrid code in XAML.

```
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="133" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,124,0,0" Name="datagrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="684" DataContext="{Binding}" 
                 RowHeaderWidth="0"       CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray"  
                      Background="White" RowBackground="#FFE7F6EC" AlternatingRowBackground="#F9F9F9" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" RowHeight="25" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                       CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
                      FontFamily="Tahoma" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
            </DataGrid>
```

As you can see I have an empty data grid initially. I add rows to this datagrid from the code. And for each row I would like to add a DataGridComboBoxColumn. I would like that combobox to bind with an existing enum below:

```
   public enum Priority : int
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Primary = 1,
        Secondary = 2,
        Tertiary = 3,
        Independent = 4,
        NA = 5,
    }
```

And I have this following code for now to add the rows with DataGridComboBoxColumn.

```
        DataGridComboBoxColumn c1 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        c1.Header = "Priority";          
        c1.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Priority));
        c1.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
        dgInsuranceCards.Columns.Add(c1);

        DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c2.Header = "Company";
        c2.Binding = new Binding("Company");
        c2.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
        dgInsuranceCards.Columns.Add(c2);


        foreach (Info Card in Cards) // Loop through List with foreach
        {
            datagrid1.Items.Add(new Info()
            {
                Priority = Card.Priority,
                Company = Card.Company,               
            });
        }
```

where Info is a class as below:

```
 public class Info
    {
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: where did you had added datagrid Column in which particular event?

Comment: Hello Ashok, I am sorry i could not get your question

Comment: developer :  I am asking you that in which particular event of datagrid or page you had added  DatagridComboboxColumn ?